# Reg Expressions Issues with Cyrillic letters

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have had problems with regular expression and Cyrillic letters in the past so I was wondering whether there was something I am doing wrong?

Here are two reproducible examples:

Example 1 - Issue with lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
latin <- "city New York, Manhattan\n1st Avenue"
cyrilic <- "град Ню Йорк, Манхатън\n1во Авеню"

stringr::str_extract(latin, pattern = "(?<=city New York, )[\\w\\s]+(?=\n)")
#returns: Manhattan

stringr::str_extract(cyrilic, pattern = "(?<=град Ню Йорк, )[\\w\\s]+(?=\n)")
stringr::str_extract(cyrilic, pattern = "(?<=град Ню Йорк, ).+(?=\n)")
#both return: NA
```

Example 2 - issue with grep's ignore.case = TRUE:

```
randomWord <- "Човек"

grep(pattern = "човек", x = randomWord, ignore.case = T)
#returns: integer(0)
```

Any ideas of how to write the regexes in order for them to work in cyrillics?

My default text encoding is UTF-8 and here is my sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Bulgarian_Bulgaria.1251  LC_CTYPE=Bulgarian_Bulgaria.1251   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Bulgarian_Bulgaria.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=Bulgarian_Bulgaria.1251
```

Comment: Make sure you *save* your script as UTF8. R Studio doesn't save files as UTF8 by default.

Comment: thanks, that is good to know. However, I am having these issues whilst using R interactively as well.

Comment: Turning on `perl = TRUE` makes the second one work.

Comment: @alistaire yeah, it does work! Thanks. 
However, it still is strange you have to add this part, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, there are still bigger issues here beyond the particular regex engine.

Comment: You are on Windows, TRE regexps do not work well with Unicode regexes there. Under Linux, they work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why `str_extract` returns `NA` in this case, as it seems that the regular expression is valid.

However `str_locate` and `str_detect` seem to work as expected:

```
stringr::str_detect(cyrilic, "(?<=град Ню Йорк, )[\\w\\s]+(?=\n)")
#returns TRUE
stringr::str_locate(cyrilic, "(?<=град Ню Йорк, )[\\w\\s]+(?=\n)")
#returns the start and end positions for Манхатън
```

A workaround solution for your problem will be to use `substr()` in combination with `str_locate`:

```
substr(cyrilic, 
   stringr::str_locate(cyrilic, "(?<=град Ню Йорк, )[\\w\\s]+(?=\n)")[1], 
   stringr::str_locate(cyrilic, "(?<=град Ню Йорк, )[\\w\\s]+(?=\n)")[2]
)
#returns 'Манхатън'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is perhaps with how ICU deals with the pattern received from stringr `str_extract`: it seems that the resulting lookbehind pattern stops being of known width. Or, there is some other bug with `str_extract`.

In this case, it is much safer to use `str_match` that has no issues with pattern length:

```
> str_match(cyrilic, pattern = "град Ню Йорк,\\s*([\\w\\s]+)\n")[,2]
[1] "Манхатън"
```

Just access the right group, here, it is the second item in the resulting list.

As for the TRE regex you used with `grep`, I also observed various issues across different environments. On my Windows 7 machine, your code returns `1`. However, TRE regex  with literal Unicode letters may fail, and the best practice is to use PCRE regex. To make it fully Unicode aware, do not forget to add `(*UCP)` PCRE verb at the pattern start so as `\w`, `\d`, etc. could match all Unicode chars. Here, it is not necessary and

```
> randomWord <- "Човек"
> grep(pattern = "човек", x = randomWord, ignore.case = T, perl=TRUE)
[1] 1
```

will work equally well.